# Hide an artifact

Tags: dnd-5e, artifacts

In my D&D 5e campaign my players have found an artifact, to be specific a *Necronomicon* (which is more or less a spellbook) and now they carried it around.

Most of the abilities of the book are already known to the players:

1. The main purpose of the book is to be found (and read) - this is its
   primary goal, everything else is secondary.
2. Because of that (point 1) its magic trace always can be detected - for now they keep it in a lead box within a *bag of holding* - even then people
   in a radius of approximately 50 feet can detect or react to the books
   aura.
3. Once completely read it basically starts the event chain for Ragnarök

   - the destruction of the current era to move on to the next one
4. It also contains all 7 great evils - they already "destroyed"
   Azmodan.
5. In order to destroy it they would have to destroy the Far Realms, so
   basically a whole plane - not really an option yet for them since
   they are lvl 10.

Since the book bugs them more and more, they are trying to hide it now - the bag of holding combination is barely working for them.  More and more monsters are chasing them for the book and they are getting pretty much super annoyed by it.

I was thinking of a logical way for how they actually can get rid of the book without "returning", but I don't want to "gift" it to them.

A few things I already ruled out:

1. Just hiding it on another plane
2. Dumping it in the sea/volcano/forest/whatever
3. Giving to some strong NPC that knows about the book, since the book
   can corrupt even the strongest and kindest mind

Is there any "smart" way to actually get the book out of their way for at least a few sessions so that they stop going crazy about it?  I want to be able to give them a "little hint" in order that they then figure it out themselves.

#### Main Reason for this, the problem to solve

The game sessions are getting more and more about discussions of how to get rid of the book instead of actually playing - which is very annoying in the long run for both sides of the DM screen.

---

Clarification about the campaign and the artifact:
The game itself is basically a "sandbox".  The idea is that players can shape the word by their own means - I did add some special items, creatures and stories throughout the world - but what really happens is up to the players. There are some "end game" and TPK scenarios planned, but what probably happen is that the world moves to next era.

The book itself has no will (like a sentient magic item would).  The 7 great evils inside it have somewhat limited power to control living beings outside, in order to get someone to "do something stupid".  Their power is strictly limited - they need a "human key" that has achieved some transition steps in order to fully activate the powers to summon all 7 evils at once.

Comment: The large section of info about the book is really a red herring and may convince the stack that this is an opinion-based question - but I don't think it is. Rather than focusing on the book, can you focus on what you want to happen in the game and provide more info there? We don't really do idea generation, but we can tell you if there is an existing mechanic that fits the bill.

Comment: And welcome to our stack! Please take the [tour] to learn more about how we operate and you can also visit the [help] for more info.

Comment: Is the book alive/aware? You described it as having a goal which is only something sentient creatures can have.

Comment: Are you able to share a little more about why you have ruled out taking it to another plane or throwing it into some kind of sea? Is there something particular about the book or world that prevents this?

Comment: Welcome to why artifacts are a tricky thing to DM for and to play around with; like the Ring Frodo had to take to Mordor, those darned things are an great inconvenience!

Comment: @NautArch About the focus of the game - the game itself is basically a "sandbox", the idea is that players can shape the word by their own means - I did add some special items, creatures and stories throughout the world - but what really happens is up to the players. There are some "end game" and TPK scenarios planned, but what probably happen is that the world moves to next era.

Comment: What magic items does the party have? I need to know all of them before I can propose an answer for you.

Comment: @Fering the book itself has no will itself, but the 7 great evils inside it have somewhat limited power to control living beeings outside, in order to get someone to "do something stupid". But their power is strictly limited - they need a "human key" that has achieved some transition steps in order to fully activate the powers to summon all 7 evils at once.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast the basic idea was actually from lord of the rings...

Comment: Since you have already narratively made it so strong that it bypasses two normal means of suppressing detection, you have created this problem for yourself to a great extent; are you looking for 'more powerful' means of suppressing detection that are in the published books? The most powerful?

Comment: Also, I need the level and class and sub class of your party.  Some assets may not be available.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast https://www.dndbeyond.com/campaigns/1549741, all characters are there, ignore the lvl 20 minotaur tho

Comment: What do you mean by "returning"?

Comment: FYI, I've voted to close for details - I think there's info we need here. If you'd like to workshop it, feel free to hop into [chat]!

Comment: You need to summarize that detail into your question.  I'll take look later.  Questions and Answers have to stand on their own on this site. Also, please join us in chat, we can do some brainstorming there.

Comment: Why have you ruled out options such as "just hide it on another plane" and "dump it in a volcano"?  If we don't understand why you're ruling out those options, any other options we give you might be ruled out for the same reasons.

Comment: Didn't one of the 5E sourcebooks (Mordenkainen's I think) say that the Far Realm isn't one specific location or time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Choose for your artifact to work differently

The problems you are having are caused by your decision about how the artifact works.  But you can just choose to make a different decision and have the artifact work in a different way.  (In that way this is very similar to a [My Guy Syndrome](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37103/what-is-my-guy-syndrome-and-how-do-i-handle-it) problem!)

If your group doesn't know all the rules of the artifact yet, you can just change those rules.  If they've already figured the rules out, you'll have to make up a reason the rules don't always apply.

- Maybe the artifact has a secret weakness, like exposure to salt, or cold iron, or the tears of a unicorn, or whatever.  Maybe the secret weakness disables some of the artifact's powers and then it can be hidden.
- In games I've run involving very noticeable artifacts, I've often allowed the group to use the *magic aura* spell to negate or weaken the artifact's magic aura.
- Maybe an ally shows up to help the party deal with the book.  If enemies are finding the party so frequently, it would make sense that allies could also find them.

Comment: I'd also add that you can just choose not to have them deal with people for whom the book is a matter of interest for a while. If you constantly throw stuff at them because of the book then of course they're going to be annoyed about the book. But not every moment of consequence needs to be about it. Give them something else to do.

Answer (score 6):

Several subanswers: an in-universe thought sandwiched by two meta/GM-ing tips

Zeroth-level note - from your description, it's not clear to me that **you** know a solution to this book besides "Well, let it end the world, I guess?"   While players can often come up with new answers to this kind of puzzle, you should be starting with at least *one* idea in hand if they need guidance.

> ...the main purpose of the book is to be found (and read) - this is
> **its** primary **goal**, everything else is secondary...
>
> ...**The book itself has no will** (like a sentient magic item would)...
>
> Giving to some strong NPC that knows about the book [would not be an
> option], since **the book** can corrupt even the strongest and kindest
> mind (Bolding mine, for emphasis)

These three statements are mutually contradictory: either this book has a mind of its own that shapes its effects, *or* it does not. Resolving that contradiction implies that you'll be adding more details to how it actually works, which is convenient.

From what you describe later, the seven great evils (or, ah, "six remaining ones"?) are the source of any direction the book's AOE has. As you are aware, per your description of overall problem, any group of over three sentient beings trying to achieve a goal has a potential to get bogged down in endless discussion of how to do it..  Communicate that to the players (using direct telepathy from the things in the book or Behavior of a controlled NPC) that currently, the Great Evils have come up with mutually conflictual ideas of **how** they'll be getting this book read, which means that for the moment, the book is actually harmless as the great evils argue and debate on their best path forward.

Alternately (or in combination), I suggest using the "there's always a bigger fish" solution: if the problem with the book is that it corrupts the incorruptible, and that if it's *read* the world ends, then give it to a being that's already 'corrupt' but in a way that means there's no chance it's interested in letting the book have its day (for example: a being that wants to **rule** the world needs the world to keep existing!)
and
a being that can't itself read and will reasonably prevent others from reading the book as well (Ex. a ancient, powerful, jealous, and very myopic chromatic dragon)

Back to meta issues:

### This is a problem you created for yourself.

It happens! We all do it.  The question is mostly how you *resolve* them.

> The game sessions are getting more and more about discussions of how to get rid of the book instead of actually playing

First of all: that *is* a kind of playing. It's a kind that's not particularly fun, but the players are still actively trying to work out how their characters will act within the constraints of the universe set for them.

Their problem is, **you've created a case** where they have no option *except* to fixate on hiding the book...

1. Left alone, the book will do undesirable things (end their world)
2. Taken with them, the book also does undesirable things ("More and more monsters are chasing them for the book and they are getting pretty much super annoyed by it.")
3. They can't get around 1 or 2 in a reasonable way (by giving it to NPCs that can prevent interference; by shielding it with the materials and methods they have) **and** they cannot destroy it.
4. Therefore, if they enter narrative play, whatever the book is doing hijacks any other things they could be doing with these characters
5. They don't like the narrative play happening when the book is having an effect (which is always.) They *have been actively trying to resolve the book situation and move on*, **but you haven't let these attempts succeed**.
6. The result is that they don't enter narrative play at all  ("...discussions... instead of [narrative] playing")

The solution is very simple: stop making adversaries show up to bring attention to the book! Only have it display any effect whatsoever when you *intend* for it to be *a current narrative focus*. Let them have a cursed object resting in their inventory for an extended period of time; there's no rush if it's not a plot thread you're currently interested in doing.

In the future: don't make concepts that start unavoidable chains of events (here "if this book exists, it will make someone use it to end the world") unless you intend for the chain to proceed at speed; if it's not supposed to be the narrative's destiny, you *always* need to give narrative accelerants a brake pedal.

Comment: Spelling and format mostly for the edits, nice answer. (We had a discussion with the OP in chat that covered quite a few of the things you address).  *tips cap*